# Bounty will not let me give less than 100 points

Tags: support, bounty

Why when setting a bounty here in this SE the minimum is 100 rep whereas on other SE sites they have a 50 reputation option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) :

> #### What is the minimum amount of rep I can offer a bounty for?
>
> For most questions, 50 reputation. There are some exceptions, though:
>
> - If you have already answered the question before, the minimum bounty offer is 100.
> - If you have already offered a bounty on the question before, the minimum offer is double your last offer (see below).

I would guess from your recent activity that you're attempting to place a bounty on [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/could-a-weather-balloon-make-a-good-antenna), which you have posted an answer to.

These adjustments are in place to [prevent abuse of the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116476/undocumented-increase-in-minimum-bounty-value) by making it expensive to perpetually promote a question or to draw attention to your own answers.